# java.lang.NullPointerException (after tried third attempt still giving the same error)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new with android development. I'm currently developing an Android Application on Face Recognition. I'm trying to run an existing source code that I obtain from github. The codes seems does not have any error(red line beneath the code). When I tried to run, the application has stopped working and gave me a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:98)
           at com.example.syafiq.testing.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:179)
```

on the highlighted error (FdActivity.java:179)

```
(line 178) ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
(line 179) actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I've tried solution that I've found on the Internet

First try:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
assert actionBar != null;
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And yet still the same error, so i tried another one that I found on the Internet.

Second try:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

The result still the same
I've tried the third one

Third try:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
Objects.requireNonNull(actionBar).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

All the three solution that I've tried still giving the same error, point to line 179

For android manifest.xml(obtain from source code on github):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

But the source code does not have style.xml file under the values folder. But my android studio include with style.xml file and the code is:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I did not use the import tools instead I've created manually (.java, .xml and other libraries that included)

Comment: Why u are using ActionBar it is depricated use Toolbar

Comment: What is your Style of your app. Try getSupportActionBar ?

Comment: I see, I obtain this code from github. But thank you :) I tried to change the ActionBar :D

Answer (score 2):

If your project build target is equal or below Android 4.4 problem may be of your Activity theme please check in manifest if u r using custom theme try using   `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` as parent

and if project build target is equal or above Android 5.0 use :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

instead of

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and also check Theme issue as above

Comment: I tried and receive another error, Three classes contain, FdActivity, PersonRecognizer and AsyncServiceHelper :/

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: Hi kapil, thank you for your new edit and help! I've tried using the solution that you gave me, it seems it gave me different error that consist an xml file Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity my project is Android 4.4.2

Comment: edited, I've included my manifest there :D

Answer (score 2):

### Your logcat throws

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:98)

1. Try with `getSupportActionBar()`
2. Use **ToolBar** instead of `ActionBar` .

Since version ***22.1.0***, the class `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. You should use `AppCompatActivity`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Comment: edited, I've included my manifest there :D

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess without you posting your xml file and manifest. Please post them and we can help you. Also in your manifest make sure you have a theme as such

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.ActionBar"
```

You can always run into npe for so many reasons.

Comment: edited, I've included my manifest there :D

Comment: What is in your style.xml?

Comment: <style name="Theme.Holo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 0):

check this activity theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` or your code whether it is something like `noactionbar`,if yes,so `getActionBar()` in your activity will be `null`;

Comment: Hi bozzmob, I've checked my AndroidManifest.xml and theres no "noactionbar" instead it use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" thanks for answering :)

Comment: edited, I've included my manifest there :D